# Writing C# formula to perform simple math on value fields for ArcGIS Reports?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, c#, reports

I'm working in ArcMap 10.1 making a report on Report Designer to compare values in the attribute table with other values.

I would like to ask how to write formulas in C# to do simple math on groups of data found in the value fields?

I have tried to create formula for the Field Types: String, Double, Int32, and Float in Report Designer but cannot create the correct format to perform division between the value fields in the report.